# Adding custom shortcode placeholders to TinyMCE 5

Tags: tinymce

i have some system codes in documents that i edit in tinymce. that codes should be represented by an interactive placeholder in the WYSIWYG editor.

It is like normal images but the result should be this Code instead (and not parsed to HTML):

```
[img]id=123&text=bla[/img]
```

[image]

I could not find any information on how to create this interactive placeholder element for custom elements...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Like this, and set as a toolbar item

```
editor.ui.registry.addMenuButton('plugins', {
   text: 'Plugin',
  fetch: function (callback) {
      var items = [
           {type: 'menuitem', text: 'Image with description', onAction: function() {editor.insertContent('[img]Hier de code[/img]');}},
          ];
callback(items);
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry, that is not what i mean. This only adds a menu button but not an placeholder für this element inside the editor.

Comment: Then add an icon or symbol  and with css create an placeholder

Comment: What i am looking for is a function that adds an object to the content of the WYSIWYG-Editor. When i click on this object an window should open where i can change the settings. After saving the image should be parsed as specific code.